# Passing JSON data in HTTPPost request from Java to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: java, android, asp.net-mvc

Im working on an Android application which i am building in Java and i have a website/REST services in an ASP.NET MVC application. I am trying to make a HttpPost request with the Java HttpClient and pass object in JSON format in the http request but they are not showing up in the controller in my MVC REST service. When i run the application and make the request form Java it breaks in the MVC application and i check the HttpContext.Request and the Params field is empty, the QueryString is empty, and all other places i look it only says "application/json" but it does not have any parameters. Does anyone have any ideas? i've followed tutorials that show how to set the entity with a StringEntity of the JSONObject but that also does not work. If i pass in paramters normally such as "http://www.url.com?name=mike&number=1" that works and i get the data in the MVC controller. Does anyone have a tutorial of some kind or can help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 there is already a built-in `JsonValueProviderFactory` which allows you to directly invoke actions using JSON. And if you are using an older version you could implement one yourself. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) to see the exact wire format that is expected.

Let's suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and you wanted to invoke the following controller action and have the argument automatically populated from the JSON request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person p)
{
    ...
}
```

you could send the following POST request:

```
POST /home/index HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:4569
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 40
Connection: close

{"FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Smith"}
```